# strace: exec: Permission denied (error), when trying to strace in linux. How do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, strace, zombie-process

I recently borrowed a code from @chrk to try and notice a zombie process with the `sudo strace -c ./<name>`, but when I run the command i get an error saying:

strace: exec: Permission denied

I use Ubuntu (Linux) to code.

Anyone has any suggestions to how to fix it? :)

Comment: Maybe `<name>` doesn't have execute permissions for everyone? Add the output of `ls -l <name>` to your post.

Comment: @JeffHolt -rwxr-xr-x 1 anna anna 9016 Mar 18 15:16 prozombie

Comment: Maybe there is more than one file whose name is `prozombie` and the current working directory from the evidence is ambiguous. Or maybe `prozombie` is being recreated and for a time its permissions are inferior but `ls` doesn't capture the problem when it manifests.